# Help with "grep" command in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, grep

I ran a command on a terminal in Ubuntu:

```
$ grep "Director"  file.lst
```

And the output of that command was

```
1006|Pankaj | Director|sales|03/09/38|6700
```

I want know the full description of the output of the command..I know the $grep command used to pattern matching...

Comment: You would have to ask your professor or whoever gave you this program.  We know nothing about it.

Comment: What exactly is your question ?  'grep` matches lines that have a specific pattern. Is that what you wanted to know ?

Comment: My question is after executing grep command  the 1st "1006" refer which thing

Comment: Traditional **`VTU`** example! 1006 is Employee ID, Followed by Name| Designation | Department | DOB | Salary, For those who wonder how I am SO sure about this :: This is a text book example from "UNIX Concepts and Applications - Sumitabha Das"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that command looked for the text "Director" in the text file `file.lst`, then returned the line of the file that contains that word.

You can run the command

```
man grep
```

in a terminal to view the manual page for the `grep` command.

There are also many, many tutorials and manuals online on how to use it; try searching for "grep tutorial" on your favorite search engine for lots of information.

Please let me know if this answer was helpful or if you have further questions.

Comment: Actually I want to know which thing refer by "1006" whether it is a size of or other.

Comment: That depends on the meaning of the contents of `file.lst`, which is just a text file. I have no idea who created that file or what they put in there, so it's impossible for me to know what the columns mean.